# Trying to stop storage data

Tags: java, android, save, sensors

I wrote this code to save sensors data in sd by .txt file. 
It works but when I press the "stop" button it doesn't stop storing data. 
Anyone can tell me why? 
About me the problem is in the LongOperation class or in the stop button, but I can't find the solution.
This is the code:

Here is the "stop" button:

```
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.end);
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Stop recording the data set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here there's the "start" button that implement the LongOperation class:

```
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go);
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
            new LongOperation().execute("");
            start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Start recording the data set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            finally {
                startFlag = true;
            }

        }
    });
```

The "LongOperation class" that saves sensors data in .txt file on sd:

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        while(true)
        {
            today.setToNow();
            int month = today.month + 1;
            String acquisition = today.monthDay + "/" + month + "/"
                    + today.year + " " + today.format("%k:%M:%S") + " ";
            File f1 = new File(sd, store_data);
            scrivi(acquisition +" "+ "ACC:"+
                    " "+String.valueOf(aX)+
                    " "+String.valueOf(aY)+
                    " "+String.valueOf(aZ)+
                     "MAG:"+
                    " "+String.valueOf(mX)+
                    " "+String.valueOf(mY)+
                    " "+String.valueOf(mZ)+
                     "GYR:"+
                    " "+String.valueOf(gX)+
                    " "+String.valueOf(gY)+
                    " "+String.valueOf(gZ)+
                    "\r\n", f1);
            //return "true";
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {}
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}

}

public void scrivi(String Data, File f) {
    FileWriter fw = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(Data);
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private final SensorEventListener AccSensorListener
            = new SensorEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
                aX = event.values[0];
                aY = event.values[1];
                aZ = event.values[2];
            }
        }
};
private final SensorEventListener MagSensorListener
        = new SensorEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD){
            mX= event.values[0];
            mY = event.values[1];
            mZ = event.values[2];
        }
    }
};
private final SensorEventListener GyrSensorListener
        = new SensorEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE){
           gX= event.values[0];
           gY= event.values[1];
           gZ= event.values[2];
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This is too much code to expect people to look through. Try cutting it down to the relevant bits. Where do you start the writing of the storage data, where do you stop the writing? And the code that actually does the writing. We don't need to see the hardware interaction bits.

Comment: how can i modify the question?

Comment: As in what do you click on or what should you delete? At the bottom of the question, just below the question tags, there's an edit link.

Comment: Is this for Android?